# Styling wicket components that are added via a repeater

Tags: wicket

I'm working with an application where I need to add sets of child panels to other containing parent panels that are part of a page.

There can be anywhere from 1 to 3 of the parent panels at a time, and between the parents there can be a total of 7 child panels.

I have it to where everything is getting added properly, but when trying to style these panels added via the wicket repeater none of my normal methods work.

I've tried overriding the populateItem method of the ListView as seen at: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-and-other-repeaters.html and https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/page-with-dynamic-components.html

```
        add(new ListView<ParentPanel>("parentPanels", panels) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<ParentPanel> item) {

            ParentPanel temp = (ParentPanel) item.getModelObject();

            temp.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("panelClass"), ""));

            item.add(temp);
        }

    });
```

...or in markup:

```
        <wicket:container wicket:id="listOfPanels">
            <wicket:panel wicket:id="panelClass"/>
        </wicket:container>
```

...or even adding an attribute modifier into the constructor of the panel being added.

All of this seems to be ignored. Am I missing something basic? If I didn't have to calculate the number and type of panels to add this wouldn't be an issue, but what does using a repeater do that removes the style?

Comment: Are you even using an html entity that is rendered? <wicket:panel> (not sure if this is even valid?) should be ignored in the final html output and so it won't matter if you change its class. Do you see any changes if the repeated item is a "real html" (div, ...) entity?

Comment: Can't you style the html for the panel inside the panels? Or are you trying to apply different classes depending on the position in the repeater?

Comment: Yeah, I am applying styles based on logic I use when processing the items from the repeater. The root of my problem was that I was definitely using the wrong tags. Works great now. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not thing giving a panel as a tepmlate to a ListView is a good practice. This may be more convenient

```
       add(new ListView<Object>("parentPanels", panels) {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Object> item) {

        ParentPanel temp = new ParentPanel("panelClass",item.getModelObject());
        //ParentPanel temp = (ParentPanel) item.getModelObject();

        temp.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("myPanel"), ""));

        item.add(temp);
    }

});
```

Also try a HTML like this

```
    <div wicket:id="listOfPanels">
        <div wicket:id="panelClass"></div>
    </div>
```

This will be generated with your css class named **myPanel**.

Also you need to add css classes to your panel's html and its components.

Comment: Thanks, I used something like this. I was unaware of best practice for the situation, was mostly going off those two sites I linked in the original question.

And yeah, the core of the problem was the html.

Answer (score 2):

add your attribute modifier to the Item and attach the Item to a html tag that is rendered like a div instead of a wicket:container which is not rendered.

you can also add the class in the Item subclass and override repeater's newItem() method to return your own. see OddEvenListItem as an example.

Comment: Yeah, never thought to check that...sort of just cut out and doctored the examples from those sites for my own needs. Went back and found the error a little while later. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Checking out OddEvenListItem gave me enough to work on, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
For simple styles, try something like following

    item.add(new AttributeAppender("style", Model.of("padding-top:23px;padding-left:5px")));
```